# Is $\exp (-\alpha\log (n)^\beta(1+o(1)))=o(1)$?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, asymptotics, estimation

Referring to [Butucea](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-2/issue-none/Adaptivity-in-convolution-models-with-partially-known-noise-distribution/10.1214/08-EJS225.full), $\hat s_n$ is an estimator of $s_k$.

In (5) on p.902 there is the statement that
$$\mathrm{P}\left(\hat{s}_n \neq s_k\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{A^2}{4} 2^{2 \beta^{\prime} / \bar{s}}(\log n)^{2\left(\delta-\beta^{\prime}\right) / \bar{s}}(1+o(1))\right)\quad \forall k\in\{1,\dots,N\}$$
where $A\in\mathbb R^+,\beta^\prime\in\mathbb R^+$, $\bar s\in(0,2]$, $\delta>\beta^\prime$.

I think this statement is made to show that $\hat s_n$ is a consistent estimator of $s_k$, i.e.

$$\forall\varepsilon>0:\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm P(|\hat s_n-s_k| > \varepsilon) = 0.$$
To show consistency one could calculate like this:

$$\mathbb P(|\hat s_n-s_k| > \varepsilon)\le\mathbb P(|\hat s_n-s_k| > 0)=\mathbb P(\hat{s}_n \neq s_k)\overset!=o(1).$$

So we have to argue that
$$\exp \left(-\frac{A^2}{4} 2^{2 \beta^{\prime} / \bar{s}}\log (n)^{2\left(\delta-\beta^{\prime}\right) / \bar{s}}(1+o(1))\right)=o(1).$$

Renaming the constants we have that for $\alpha,\beta>0$ must hold
$$\exp \left(-\alpha\log (n)^\beta(1+o(1))\right)=o(1).$$

Here I am not really sure why this should be true for $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $n\to\infty$, $\log(n)^{\beta}\to\infty$ and consequently $-\alpha\log(n)^{\beta}\to-\infty$. Since $1+o(1)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\alpha\log(n)^{\beta}(1+o(1))=-\infty\cdot 1=-\infty$$
$$\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(-\alpha\log(n)^{\beta}(1+o(1))\right)=\exp(-\infty)=0$$